Set Target Inclination of Hometrainer with BLE
I'm currently trying to include the incline angle over BLE with the Fitness Machine Control Point characteristic with Python Bleak. I'm pretty sure that the correct characteristic is "00002ad9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb".
But I dont know how to give the command to the hometrainer to accept the inclination.  Only found a document about Fitness Machine Services that includes the characteristic I'm using. Here is the whole pdf ("Fitness Machine Service 1.0").
And the part with inclination.
Here is my code, I tried to implement it with a byte built with the op code and the desired inclination.
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

async def set_fitness_machine_values(uuid):
    address = "C5:B3:F0:FB:9A:1E"
    target_inclination = int(target_inclination_percent * 10)
    inclination_bytes = target_inclination.to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True)
    op_code = 0x03
    payload = bytes([op_code]) + inclination_bytes

    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
            await client.write_gatt_char(uuid, payload)

            
target_inclination_percent = 5.0

asyncio.run(set_fitness_machine_values("00002ad9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))

Here is the error:
bleak.exc.BleakError: Could not write value b'\x032\x00' to characteristic 0031: Protocol Error 0x81: Unknown

I tried to request control with the op code \x00 and after that tried to set the inclination but for some reason my script isnt even able to request control and i get the same error, even though the charactersistic im using is the correct one (Fitness Machine Control Point write,indicate). Why am i not able to write anything to my hometrainer? It supports the characteristic but it looks like it cant write or accept any value.
Trying other characteristics also doesnt work.

Welcome to [SO]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [what you are asking] page for details on how to best help us help you.
DO NOT post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

I dont understand what the problem of my post is. I tried something out, it didnt work and now I just ask people if they have any advice.
